# mark LaTeX keywords in listings

Tags: listings, keywords

I am using this code to define keywords for listings

```
\lstdefinestyle{demostyle}{
    columns=flexible,
    keepspaces=true,    
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    language = [LaTeX]TeX,
    morekeywords={textwidth,color,let},
}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}
```

However that marks every word `color` as a keyword, no matter if it is preceded by a `\`.

I however really want only LaTeX keywords to be highlighted.

Can this somehow be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `moretexcs`, I think

```
\lstdefinestyle{demostyle}{
    columns    = flexible,
    keepspaces = true,    
    basicstyle = \small\ttfamily,
    language   = [LaTeX]TeX,
    moretexcs  = {textwidth,color,let},
}
```

Comment: I switched to morekeywords for some reason I can not remember. Is there a limit on the number of codewords ? Speed of compilation does not matter.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech No idea about a limit:  I've certainly not found one in `siunitx`, where the list is pretty big.